# c3p0 pool executing with another applications

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have few desktop java and delphi applications using firebird as dbms. Java apps use jpa/hibernate and c3p0. Sometimes the java apps can't create a new pool and simply hangs at hibernate initialization. I supposed that could be a pool problem, but I always close my resources after use. If I use a pure jdbc connection or a delphi connection, works even with hibernate apps hangs util the firebird server restart.

I've no idea what that it can be. C3p0 controls the pool even after apps shutdown? I think not.

P.S: Lately, java apps used to not use c3p0. But this doesn't exist anymore.

Here's my c3p0 config

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout" value="15000"/>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
      value="org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="180"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime" value="120"/>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20"/>
    <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
</properties>
```

Do you have some idea what it can be?

Comment: When the java application hangs next time, please take a thread dump and see where the startup thread is hanging by reading the stacktrace. It will give you ideas as to where the issue is. Also it's worth trying out checking statistics on database server if the max connections limit is not exceeded. Also worth trying is upgrading the c3pool as I have in my experience faced few bugs in getting connections which were solved by upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I checked once and hangs in EntityManagerFactory.getEntityManager() call. The database connection limit was ok and the another delphi apps still open connection normally. I was using hibernate-c3p0-4.3.1.Final and I'll try to update.

Comment: If possible post the relevant stack trace